# how to convert json data from crm dynamics to csv file with nifi

Tags: json, csv, dynamics-crm, apache-nifi

I want to convert json data from crm dynamics to csv using nifi

I used - httpinvoke processor
- convertrecord
- updateattribute
but still not convert data to csv

Comment: What's the issue/error/exception?

Comment: it's a jsonpathexception unrecognized token https : was expecting (json string,number,array...)